# Need to send information to a url, chosen from a select tag in a from with JSP

Tags: html, jsp

everyone, I hope you can help me. I need to go to page 1 or 2, depending on what the user chose from the select tag. What do I have to write in the as an attribute for "action"? Thank you in advance. This is my code:

```
<form method = "get" action = "">
   <input type = "text" name = "user" >
   <select name = "form">
        <option value = "1.jsp" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option value = "2.jsp">2</option>
   </select>
   <input type = "submit" value = "Enter">
</form>
```

Comment: What did you try? On Post all the values inside from tag gets posted to the server.

Comment: but still, it doesn't direct me to the page, that I choose.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to write in the as an attribute for "action"?

One way to do it is to post the form back to itself, so basically leave action blank or put in the file name of the same file.

then you use jsp to check for form submission, and get hte value, redirecting as necessary.

Comment: actually, there is a "text" parameter in the form that I want to send to one of the pages.